# Proving the that inverse of the rotation matrix is equal to the transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that:

If I have the matrix Mrot = [[cosx,-sinx],[sinx,cosx]] , the inverse and the transpose are the same.

I understand the inverse acts as a sort of "inverse button" but,I cannot see how the inverse and transpose matrices are the same. I am currently in freshman linear algebra.

Thanks

Comment: What methods do you know to find the inverse of a matrix?\

Comment: I can do guassian elimination or use the methods of cofactors and minors. I am also permitted to use the inversion formula for 2 by 2.

Comment: It's much easier to take the transpose than to compute the inverse. Take the transpose and prove it is the inverse by matrix multiplication (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4):

You can prove this by direct computation.
Take the transpose of $M$ to get
$$
M^{\intercal}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos x & \sin x\\
-\sin x & \cos x
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Multiply this by $M$ to get
$$
MM^{\intercal}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(x)^{2}+\sin(x)^{2}\\
 & \cos(x)^{2}+\sin(x)^{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and apply a certain famous identity.

Comment: We will also need to prove that $M^TM = I$ so that $M^T = M^{-1}$.

Comment: Indeed. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i).